# Transact-SQL update another cell of the updated row

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger which works like this:

1. I update a BIT type cell
2. the trigger sets a date cell to the current date

SQL:

```
UPDATE OrderDB.dbo.Orders SET DateCompleted = GETDATE();
```

This updates all the dates to the current one, but it's not really cool. :) I'd like to have the current row updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dateTrigger ON [dbo].[Orders] AFTER UPDATE AS
<the part i have no idea about>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a trigger for the update event the two virtual tables `deleted`and`inserted`will contain the changed row(s) (deleted holds pre-update, and inserted holds post-update), and in your trigger you can reference them, and provided you have some way to uniquely identify the rows (like a primary key - maybe OrderID in this case?) you can join the `inserted`table to determine what row(s) to update the DateCompleted field.

Something like this would do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dateTrigger ON [dbo].[Orders] AFTER UPDATE AS
IF ( UPDATE (status) )
BEGIN
  UPDATE [dbo].[Orders] SET DateCompleted = GETDATE() 
  FROM [dbo].[Orders]
  INNER JOIN inserted ON [dbo].[Orders].[OrderID] = inserted.[OrderID]
END;
```

Note that this trigger checks if a column named`status`has been updated, it won't fire if you update any other column.

Comment: You DID help me a lot! Thank you! I'd been reading all over the net, but everywhere I saw a lot of heavily complicated examples. Thanks again. :)